# wxPython gauge freezes on Linux

Tags: python, linux, wxpython

I'm struggling with wxPython on Linux. After a lot of time and investigation I have reduced my program to the minimum to show you one of the issues I have encountered. I could reduce it to a quite small code example using only one gauge in the window which is updated by a Timer. My first problems appeard with buttons whose background color should have been changed quickly, this has resulted in strange memory faults. Since the complete application is far to complex I have searched for an easy example - bingo! Here is the reduced code which runs fine on Windows and does not on Raspberry Pi as well as VirtualBox VMs of Raspberry Pi and Debian 9. I have tried wxPython 3.0.2.0 and 4.0.3, each with gtk2 and python 2.7 and python 3.5:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*-

import wx
from threading import Timer

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Test", size=(600, 100))
        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        self.gauge = wx.Gauge(panel, wx.ID_ANY, 100, (10, 10), (480, 10))
        self.gaugeval = 0
        self.gauge.SetValue(self.gaugeval)

        self.Show()
        Timer(1, self.loop).start()

    def loop(self):
        self.gaugeval += 1
        if self.gaugeval > 100:
            self.gaugeval = 0
        self.gauge.SetValue(self.gaugeval)
        Timer(0.01, self.loop).start()


app = wx.App(False)
frame = MainWindow()
app.MainLoop()
```

After starting the program it takes one second until the gauge should "live" and fill the bar from the left to the right, then beginning again at the left and so on. However, on any of the tested Linux systems it freezes very quickly.

What is happening here? Can anyone reproduce this? I can hardly believe that such a simple function will not work. Thanks a lot for having a look at this issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that your issue may be to do with using `Timer` from the threading module.
Use `wx.Timer`.

```
import wx

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Test", size=(600, 100))
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.onTimer, self.timer)
        self.gauge = wx.Gauge(panel, wx.ID_ANY, 100, (10, 10), (480, 10))
        self.Show()
        self.timer.Start(100) # fire every 10th of a second

    def onTimer(self, evt):
        val = self.gauge.GetValue()
        val += 1
        if val > 100:
            val = 0
        self.gauge.SetValue(val)

app = wx.App(False)
frame = MainWindow()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Thanks, looks really good now! However, I will have to see how to integrate this in the real program which is much more complex. There the timer is running in another process and the call for updating the gauge is sent over a pipe. Anyway, very helpful approach. :-)

Comment: FYI: Using wx.CallAfter seemed to solve all problems caused by parallel processes, timers, threads. Your answer brought me on the right track to check threadsafe methods:
https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/05/22/wxpython-and-threads/

Comment: @skrohmer Glad to see that you kept your nose to the grindstone and resolved it using a method compatible with your requirements.